# Doing a MySQL REPLACE INTO in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

Suppose i have more than 180k user object, and some of them are already present in table, and the table has email Id unique index, So i want to update the existing records and insert the new records,

In MySQl i came to know that there is option called [REPLACE INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html), Is there any way to run the REPLACE INTO in django ORM object, and also i want run the query as bulk like below

```
Entry.objects.**bulk_replace**([
...     Entry(headline='This is a test'),
...     Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
... ])
```

Comment: But the `REPLACE INTO` does not work in bulk.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, Is there option to run replace into without bulk in django? (as like single insert model.objects.create())

Comment: Note that you can drop down to raw SQL : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly